# Something stuck inside the spark plug barrel of motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, ignition, sparkplugs

I went about changing the spark plugs on my 91' Honda CBR250RR and ran into a problem with the fourth plug. I tried inserting the sparkplug socket but it wouldn't get in there.

Using my phones camera I caught a glimpse of this stuck in the barrel..[image: ?]

Has anyone run into something like this? (this is the first time I'm changing the spark plugs on this bike since buying it about 18months ago).

It seems like solidified metal almost but I'm not sure. I need to find a way of fishing this out, any ideas?

Comment: Try to dislodge it by blasting it with compressed air

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My only suggestions would be:

- Use compressed air, as Zaid suggested
- Use a narrow screwdriver

Make sure you don't lose it - worthwhile getting a closer look at it to see if you can identify where it came from!

Comment: Hi @Rory, I tried reaching it with a narrow screwdriver and a similar tool to that of the one in Paulsters comment. But its a tight squeeze and its hard to get at it at the right angle. Luckily it did appear to move around a little so I'm hoping an air compressor would do the job.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to dislodge it. I would use something like this tool:

[image: Snapon tool under $8]

Then, before you go to remove the spark plug, take a shop vac and vacuum the piece out of there. If you hold the shop vac's hose half-way over the hole, the air turbulence should remove the small piece of debris. Also, if the piece is ferrous in nature, the hook I showed above should also be magnetized and should pull the piece out as well. Handy little tool for many different situations.